# Why is integer is showing negatively?

Tags: php

This is the code

```
<?php
$result =((7.4331585723947)**24);
echo (int)(3*$result);
?>
```

Output:

```
-6779465221961940992
```

How and why is it negative and wrong integer?

Comment: The floating number is too big (2.4281907525077E+21) and you happen to end up with a negative number, it could as well have been positive. The important thing is that it overflowed the maximum allowed integer number. See: [PHP_INT_MAX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max).

Comment: This question can be done by a Junior, not from a "8 years Developer how made more than 100 sites"

Answer (score 0):

Casting very large numbers to int is uncharted territory. This is documented at [Converting to integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) (emphasis mine):

> If the float is beyond the boundaries of int (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), **the result is undefined**, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact int result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!